# Exception in creating batch relationship between nodes while using py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have created a graph database using py2neo and the purpose is:

- Create one node for each city. The node stores city name and a unique id associated with it.
- Create one node for each airport. The airport node stores airport name and again a unique id.
- Create a relationship between city node and airport node if the airport is in that city.

I created city nodes first (successfully) using this module:

```
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)    
for city_id,city_name in <some_list>:
     city_node_id = batch.create(node(city_id=city_id, name=city_name))
     batch.add_indexed_node('city_index','city_id',city_id, city_node_id)
batch.submit()
```

Then in another separate module I tried to create airport nodes and relationship between the airport node and corresponding city node like this:

```
read_batch = neo4j.ReadBatch(graph_db)
write_batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
for airport_id, city_id, airport_name in <some_list>:
    airport_node_id = write_batch.create(node(airport_id=airport_id, city_id=city_id, name=airport_name)) 
    write_batch.add_indexed_node('airport_index','airport_id',airport_id, airport_node_id)
    city_node_id = read_batch.get_indexed_nodes('city_index','city_id',city_id)
    rel_id = write_batch.create(rel(airport_node_id, "is in city", city_node_id))
    write_batch.add_indexed_relationship('airport_rel_index','airport_id',airport_id, rel_id)
write_batch.submit()
```

The 3rd statement from last wherein I am creating relationships is throwing exception:

```
rel_id = write_batch.create(rel(airport_node_id, "is in city", city_node_id))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 2695, in create
"to": self._uri_for(entity.end_node)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 2537, in _uri_for
uri = "{{{0}}}".format(self.find(resource))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 2528, in find
raise ValueError("Request not found")
  ValueError: Request not found
```

I tried to print uri of both the types of nodes. Their is a difference:

```
print station_node_id._uri, city_node_id._uri
```

Output:

```
node index/node/city_index/city_id/2536650
```

So the uris of both nodes are different, which is why I guess the relationship is not getting created.

What function can I use which returns the unindexed node for city i.e. uri should be just "node" instead of the "index/node/city_index/city_id/".

Is there any other way to create this relationship?

I would be happy to provide any other information if need be.
Thanks in advance!

Neo4j: 1.9.5

py2neo: 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is an unfortunate server limitation whereby the Location URIs returned by some REST calls contain a node index entry URI instead of a standard node URI. This is unfortunately useful only in a few use cases and a major limitation in cases like yours.

There is a similar issue discussed here - https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/221 - and unfortunately nothing I can do from the client side.

Your only real option is to split your work into multiple batches or - if you are able to do so - consider an upgrade to Neo4j 2.0 where you can use the new label and schema index capabilities.

Comment: I upgraded to neo4j 2.0 but still the issue persists. In my case, the problem cannot be solved even if I do the second module in different batches because what I need is **node_id** when **city_id** is given. And whatever I do the node id returned using the **city_index** is always that of index and not original node. Is there something I am missing? Thanks Nigel!

Comment: I even tried using separate batch for creating relationships in graph but even that did not work.

Comment: The BatchRequests returned by the WriteBatch methods are merely placeholders for return values, not the return values themselves. If you gather the results from the `submit` call, you will find the nodes that are created. You can then use these in a subsequent batch for creating the relationships.